# How to implement the disposable pattern in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I know the disposable pattern from C#.

However, I wonder a little bit on how it is implemented and used in Dart and Flutter. I saw it being used in Flutter like this:

```dart
@override
void dispose() {
    // dispose own stuff here
    super.dispose();
}
```

Now it's the first time I wanted to implement it myself in a class without a widget base class. In some library, I found a [Disposable](https://pub.dev/documentation/w_common/latest/disposable/Disposable-class.html) base class and the [dispose()](https://pub.dev/documentation/w_common/latest/disposable/Disposable/dispose.html) method.

However, the method signature is different

```dart
@override
Future<Null> dispose() async {

}
```

In C#, there is an interface one needs to implement in order to satisfy the disposable pattern. Does such an interface (base class) exist for Dart? Or is it just that everyone implements a dispose method with an arbitrary signature and whoever uses the class must be smart enough to find the method and figure out how to call it?

Comment: dispose is not a destructor. It doesn't get called automatically. The plugin developer or class creator needs to call this method at the time of cleanup. The flutter framework as well calls this method as lifecycle method.

Comment: Your last line is what is followed. Everyone is smart enough to call it (at least for now). Dart is evolving and we might see changes related to this in future.

Comment: @Rahul: ok. For now I think I will implement a destructor and call dispose() of whatever needs to be disposed.

Comment: @ThomasWeller You shouldn't try to do it that way just because that's how it's managed in .NET. In general, you should work with immutable classes in Flutter/Dart. For all classes with a state you use a package of your choice or StatefulWidgets. Managing the disposing by yourself is extremely error-prone and not intended in Flutter.

Comment: @Mäddin: thanks for making me think. Maybe I didn't implement a business logic object. Maybe I actually implemented a widget and that class should belong to the UI layer. I'll need to get that sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method that is always called when an object is "disposed". Depending on the state management system you use, this is handled differently.
I would (personally) recommend a state management system with `Provider` and/or `Bloc`. Here you can use e.g. the method `close` to release your resources when a `Bloc` is removed from the widget tree.
https://pub.dev/packages/provider
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc

Other state management systems:
https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

If you just use `StatefulWidget`s for your state management (not recommended), you use the `dispose` method to free your resources.

EDIT:
As @RandalSchwartz said, my answer was not fully correct. There is the [Finalizer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Finalizer-class.html) class in Dart that allows you to dispose objects once they become unreachable.
However, this is not best practice in Flutter and should not be used as a general pattern.

Comment: Well, almost correct, however, with the Finalizer class, you can get disposal notifications.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Yes, you can do that of course, but it's definitely not a best practice and again quite error prone. But you are right. I'll add it to my answer.